# Vimeo Threejs Player with live events

Tags: three.js, webgl, vimeo

I am currently using the [vimeo-threejs-player](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-threejs-player) library to show a Vimeo video in my WebGL app.
The code is basically:

```
vimeoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player(vimeo_video_id, { autoplay: false, loop: false });
vimeoPlayer.load();
vimeoPlayer.on('videoLoad', function(videoTexture) {
  //code to set the 3d object texture from the video
}
```

This is working fine with current video files uploaded, but now I am trying to visualize a Vimeo live stream using the same method, but the library is returning following error when the `vimeoPlayer.load()` is called:

```
vimeo-threejs-player.min.js?v=15:10 Uncaught (in promise) Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'link' of undefined
    at vimeo-threejs-player.min.js?v=15:10
```

And it never gets to the `videoLoad` callback function.
It seems that the /vimeo/api service is returning an unexpected result for this library.

Once the live event is done, and it is stored as a regular video, it works fine, as with any other regular video file uploaded.

In the other hand, it is stated in [vimeo-depth-player](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-depth-player) that the vimeo-threejs-player is used to play a live stream video (demo is not currently working), and code in this [example](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-depth-player/blob/master/examples/live.html) is mainly the same that I am using.

Do you have any idea of why it can be failing?